# How to plot a blackbody radiation curve?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that calculates the Planck function, given a wavelength and a specific temperature. Then, I want to plot out the range of wavelengths emitted at temperatures of 255K, 300K, and 6000K. But I cannot figure out how to get it right, and I'm starting to lose my mind over it. This is the code I have so far:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(rmarkdown)

planck = function(w,t){
 c<-2.998*10^8
 h<-6.626*10^-34
 kB<-1.381*10^-23
 a<-2*h*(c^2)
 b<-(w^5)*(exp((h*c)/(kB*w*t))-1)
 planck <- a/b
}

w<-1e-7:1e-4

P255<-planck(w,255)
P300<-planck(w,300)
P6000<-planck(w,6000)

plot(P255, log="xy", xlab='Wavelength (m)', ylab='Intensity (W m^-2 Sr^-1 um^-1)', type='l', col='blue', lwd=2 )
lines(P300,type='l', col='green', lwd=2 )
lines(P6000, type='l', col='red', lwd=2 )
```

This is the chart that I get. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Edit: I posted my code in the wrong order. I fixed it.

Comment: Your code is attempting to plot the results *before* you’ve computed them. Make sure your code is executed in the right order.

Comment: I think I pasted parts of my code in the wrong order. I still have the same problem.

Comment: I'm getting `w` equal to just one element, namely `1e-7`. Maybe you need `w <- (1:1000)/1e7` or something like that. Whenever you have plotting problems, maybe the first thing to look at is the input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
w<-1e-7:1e-4
```

with

```
n<-500
w<-seq(from=1e-7,to=1e-4,length.out=n)
```

and optionally increase `n` for smoother lines.

Comment: This is good but I would recommend a sequence that is evenly spaced in "log space" and not linear space, otherwise most of the points will be clustered on the left and the line will not be smooth on the righthand side of the x-axis. Solution: `w <- exp(seq(from = log(1e-7), to = log(1e-4), length.out = n))`